# Javascript not working when using dompdf through cron jobs

Tags: javascript, php, dompdf

I am calling a php page using include function and converting the page into PDF using Dompdf library. Everything is working fine. But the javascript written in that PHP page is not working. Actually what I am doing is that, I have written a javascript code to shuffle some contents in a PHP page and I am converting that PHP page into PDF using Dompdf, but the contents are not getting shuffled. The javascript is working well when I am directly hitting the template1.php page in browser but that is not working when I am setting the page1.php page in cron jobs.

page1.php

```
<?php
$cust_details=array();
$db='';
getTemplate(1, 1, $cust_details, $db);
    function getTemplate($no=1, $i, $cust_details,$db){
        $customer_information = $cust_details;
        $the_template= 'template1.php';
        
        callDompdf($the_template,$i,$no,$cust_details,$db);
        
    }
    function callDompdf($outputtempl,$i,$templateno,$cust_details,$db){
        ob_start();
        include $outputtempl;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_get_clean();
        
        
            
            $dompdf = new Dompdf();
            $dompdf->loadHtml($contents);
            $options = $dompdf->getOptions(); 
            $options->set(array('isRemoteEnabled' => true, 'isJavascriptEnabled'=> true));
            $dompdf->setOptions($options);
            $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
            // Render the HTML as PDF
            $dompdf->render();
            $pdf = $dompdf->output();
            $filename='reading_'.$i.'_'.$templateno.'_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'.time().'.pdf';
            $filepath='pdf/'.$filename;
            $data=file_put_contents($filepath,$pdf);
            unset($dompdf);
            unset($data);
           
    }
```

template1.php

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <span id="p_shuffle_0">Outcomes</span>
    <span id="p_shuffle_1">Actions</span>
    <span id="p_shuffle_2">Actions</span>
    <span id="p_shuffle_3">Circumstances</span>
    <span id="p_shuffle_4">Soulmate</span>
    <?php echo '<script>
        //shuffle();
        const contentArr = ["Outcomes", "Actions", "Actions", "Circumstances", "Soulmate"];
        var newshuffle= shuffle(contentArr);
        function shuffle(array) {
            let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
    
            // While there remain elements to shuffle.
            while (currentIndex != 0) {
    
                // Pick a remaining element.
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex--;
    
                // And swap it with the current element.
                [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
                array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
            }
    
            return array;
        }
    newshuffle.forEach(shuffleContent);
        function shuffleContent(value, index, array) {
            // i is the index of content you want to use depending on which content you want
            const newContent = contentArr[index];
            const shuffleP = document.getElementById("p_shuffle_"+index);
            shuffleP.textContent = newContent;
    
            
            
        }
        </script>';
?>
    </body>
```

Comment: How are you calling that script in your cron job? There's (probably) no client involved that can handle JS

Comment: I am not calling script in the cron job individually. I have set the page1.php in cron and I am calling the template1.php page using include function, but the script written in that page is not working.

Comment: So then, how are you calling that page1.php script? Can your script handle/run JS?

Comment: my domain is www.abc.com/page1.php. I have set the cron job with this domain path. Everything is wokring fine. The PDF is also getting generated, but the javascript shuffling is not working.

Comment: Javascript runs in a browser. Php by itself cannot execute Javascript. Reorganise your script so all the necessary tasks are done by php. The JS just seems to be doing some shuffling based on a random number. There's no reason php could not do that.

Comment: So what shall I do now? How will the javascript code work?

Comment: Use a headless browser. Or "convert" your JS to PHP as suggested

Comment: `How will the javascript code work?`....did you actually read what I wrote? Once more, for clarity: **Reorganise your script so all the necessary tasks are done by php**

Comment: I have enclosed the javascript code inside php tag in template1.php and now also not working.

Comment: `I have enclosed the javascript code inside php tag` ???? Why do you expect that to work? You seem to have no understanding of the basics. JavaScript is not PHP. PHP is not JavaScript. They are two entirely separate languages which run in entirely separate environments. The PHP interpreter cannot execute JavaScript code. That JavaScript can only be executed by a web browser (which contains a JavaScript runtime engine). When you run the PHP script via cron, it's basically like running PHP from a command window...so there is no browser involved.

Comment: You cannot put JavaScript code (or any other code, e.g. C#, python, ruby or whatever) inside a `<?php` tag and expect it to magically turn into PHP code. A moment spent stopping to think properly really ought to have put that idea straight out of your head. You need to **rewrite** your JavaScript code in PHP, to produce the same effect that the JavaScript is currently achieving when you run it from a browser.

Comment: But how to do that?

Comment: How to do what? How to rewrite it, you mean? First step is to understand what the JS is doing. It basically moves the `<span` tags around randomly. Now you have to sit down and think through how you could achieve the same end result using PHP. Then you try to write some code. Same way you solve any programming problem, really! Are you stuck on a specific aspect of that?

Comment: Basically instead of having the spans there as static HTML, and then using JS to manipulate them after they've been loaded into the page, you need to write PHP code which takes the array, puts it in random order, and then echoes some `<span` tags based on the randomised order of the array.

Comment: I have tried and it worked accordingly after converting javascript code to PHP. Thanks sir.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to post your solution as an Answer below, then others with a similar scenario might know the approach to solve it, and can also vote on it if they like it!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the solution sir @Adyson,
Here is the solution that works for me,

```
function shuffle_assoc($my_array)
    {
        $keys = array_keys($my_array);

        shuffle($keys);

        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $new[$key] = $my_array[$key];
        }

        $my_array = $new;

        return $my_array;
    }
    $content1='This is content1';
    $content2='This is content2';
    $content3='This is content3';
    $content4='This is content4';
    $position_names= array("P1"=>$content1, "P2"=>$content2, "P3"=>$content3, "P4"=>$content4);
    $shufflearr=shuffle_assoc($position_names);
<?php 
                $i=0;
                foreach ($shufflearr as $key=>$value){$i++;?>
                        
                        <h4><strong>Position <?php echo $i;?>: <?php echo $key;?></strong></h4>
                        <div id="content_<?php echo $i;?>">
                        <?php echo $value;?>
                        </div>
                        
                <?php }?>
```